# Why logrotate did nothing but complained no errors?

Tags: nginx, logrotate

The answer maybe obvious to you, but I am beginning to run my first logrotate instance.
The configuration in /etc/logrotate.d

```
    /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log {
        size 1k
        dateext
        missingok
        rotate 10
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root root 
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                [ -f /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid ] && kill -USR1 `cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```

Then I tested it with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate -dvf /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

And got following
    reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
    reading config info for /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log

```
Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log  forced from command line (10 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20140724'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log to /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log-20140724
creating new /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log mode = 0640 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
running script with arg /mnt/nginx/logs/access.log : "
                [ -f /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid ] && kill -USR1 `cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
"


Before test
total 84K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51K Jul 22 15:05 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24K Jul 15 17:02 error.log


After test
total 84K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51K Jul 22 15:05 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24K Jul 15 17:02 error.log
```

There was exactly nothing changed. And it didn't complain errors.
Can you please help this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake.
-d option should not be used.
But since it actions as such, why not call it "dry" run?